# Crash trying to add views to a Table dynamically (Android)

Tags: android

I want to implement something like this(**RTL**) :

[image]

In other words, being able to add views to a layout in 3 columns.
I tried doing this:

my_fragment.xml:

```
...
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/myTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/background_color">
        </TableLayout >
...
```

myFragment.java:

```
  TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[ serverResponse.getData().size()/3 ];
    for( int i=0, j=0; i<serverResponse.getData().size() ;i++ )
    {
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_item, tableRows[j], true);
        ((TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.viewText)).setText(serverResponse.getData().get(i).getItemData());
        if( i%3 == 0 ) {
            j++;
        }

        myTable.addView( tableRows[i] , new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
   }
```

Crash : `Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup`

**EDIT :**
thanks to Mike M.'s solution it now works. However, one column is always cut :
[image]

The data_item.xml is simple :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're initializing the array of `TableRow`s, but you're not initializing the individual elements, so they're `null`.

Comment: I'm confused.. the elements should receive the customViews.. which happens in the "inflate" part. No?

Comment: Each element in an array of `Object`s needs to be initialized. When you just initialize the array, each element is `null`. That is, you need to call `new TableRow(getContext())` for each new row. Also, your logic is a little off for creating your table. You're better off using two nested `for` loops.

Comment: Is your `data_item` layout supposed to be just one cell each in the table?

Comment: data_item is a view in each cell. there are 3 cells in a row.
Just like in the image I put in the post. 
I just don't know how many views like this I would need beforehand. Only after I receive response from the server.

Comment: Oh, right, I see it now. I had images turned off in my browser. Well, whichever way you want to do it, one loop or two. However, along with calling `new` for each `TableRow`, you need to `addView()` each of the `customView`s. Inflating them into the `TableRow` isn't going to do what you expect. I can work up an example, if you like, when I get chance after a bit, if someone else hasn't helped you by then.

Comment: Well that would be terrific!, since I've been trying all day long to solve that with gridview, and now with tablelayout and I just can't manage this to work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're not initializing the individual elements of your `TableRow` array. Initializing the array itself does not initialize the elements. That is, you need to instantiate a new `TableRow` for each array index.

Also, you'll need to add the cells to each `TableRow` with the `addView()` method, rather than inflating them into it, or each new cell with occupy the whole row.

```
final int size = serverResponse.getData().size();
final int numCols = 3;
final int numRows = size / numCols + (size % numCols == 0 ? 0 : 1);
final TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[numRows];

final TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams =
    new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams =
    new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                              TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                              1);

for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    tableRows[i] = new TableRow(getContext());
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        final int index = i * numCols + j;
        final View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_item,
                                                 tableRows[i], false);
        if (index < size) {
            ((TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.noteText))
                .setText(serverResponse.getData().get(index).getItemData());
        }
        else {
            ((ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.circle))
                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        tableRows[i].addView(customView, rowParams);
    }
    myTable.addView(tableRows[i], tableParams);
}
```

In the `data_item` layout, set an ID of `circle` on the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you ! It seems to work. 
Just one more thing, if I may : how can I make it RTL instead of the default LTR(when supporting right-to-left languages , it seems disarranged and cut, even in fact it's just a matter of alignment).

Comment: Also, why does the last parameter has to be 'false' in the inflating part?

Comment: I changed the data_item layout so its gravity would be 'right'. It aligns it right now but it's cut. and the columns aren't the same size.

Comment: I've editted the post with how it looks now(right column is always cut). It looks as if it doesn't care about the stretchColumns value in TableLayout for some reason..
Thanks again for the help))

Comment: or maybe it does care.. it just takes the widest column and assigns its width to the rest , but there's no room for all..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110556/discussion-between-bvtp-and-mike-m).

Comment: I just did that, but now the middle column texts are ".." (just two dots) .
Like this :
http://s32.postimg.org/ubl1x5jv9/Untitled333.png

Comment: oh no it's my bad! I accidentally had shrinkColumns=1 instead of *.

Comment: thank you it works like a charm!
can the columns be the same width though? cause right columns are different width